# Firebase Trigger email and SMTP connection URI using GMAIL

Tags: firebase, gmail, firebase-extensions

I am trying to set up TRIGGER EMAIL to send emails through my GMAIL account. My problem is definitely in the SMTP connection URI because the same configuration works fine with the SENDGRID SMTP connection URI.

So I think the problem is specifically with GMAIL.

After enabling access to third-party applications in GMAIL, I have tried:

- smtps://mymail@gmail.com:PASSWORD@smtp.gmail.com:465
- smtps://mymail@gmail.com:PASSWORD@smtp.gmail.com
- smtp://mymail@gmail.com:PASSWORD@smtp.gmail.com:25
- smtp://mymail@gmail.com:PASSWORD@smtp.gmail.com

and the same variants with %40 instead of @

I always get errors like: **Error: Invalid login:**

Are you managed to get GMAIL to work with FIREBASE TRIGGER MAIL?

Sorry for my english

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 3):

#### Update 10/2022 | 3rd party apps is deprecated!!!

As [Miroslav Kuťák](https://stackoverflow.com/users/949962/miroslav-ku%C5%A5%C3%A1k) pointed out:

> From May 30, 2022, ​​Google no longer supports the use of third-party apps or devices which ask you to sign in to your Google Account using only your username and password. https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255

---

The error message is quite explicit and seem that has to do with User's Authentication.

1. Enable [Less secure apps & your Google Account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) for that user.

You can enabled it [Here](https://myaccount.google.com/security), scroll to the bottom and you will is it.
**IMPORTANT NOTE**: Most of the time may take up to 48 hours!

If you have [2 Step verification](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185839?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) Then **DON'T** enable the Less secure Apps (it won't work) and create [Create and use app passwords](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en-GB) The password can be Used for 1 App only.

---

2. With the affected User, go to [UnlockCaptcha](http://Allow%20access%20to%20your%20Google%20Account:%20accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha), make sure that if the **ONLY** user logged in the session an no other Google account is, so unlockcaptcha.

---

3. If still not work try:

   ```
   smtps://mymail@gmail.com:PASSWORD@smtp.gmail.com:587
   ```

Allow access to your Google Account: accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

Comment: From May 30, 2022, ​​Google no longer supports the use of third-party apps or devices which ask you to sign in to your Google Account using only your username and password. https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?authuser=4&hl=en&authuser=4&visit_id=638012484958992490-3525698788&p=less-secure-apps&rd=1

Comment: @MiroslavKuťák, added in the answer, thanks to report it!

Comment: is there still a way to use gmail account for that Email Trigger now that less secure app access is no longer supported?

Comment: Solved it: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833
You need to add "Sign in with App Password"

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to have Google Workspace set up

Then try this:
smtp://mymail@mydomain.com:PASSWORD@smtp-relay.gmail.com:587

Comment: nope, `smtp-relay.gmail.com` is completely another kind of smtp service.